# How do you disable password-expiration on a newly-flashed copy of Ubuntu Server LTS for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi, password

I've flashed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS onto an SD card, enabled SSH by adding the empty `ssh` file at the system root, and then SSH'ed into the Raspberry Pi with the username `ubuntu`:

```
❯ ~ [22s] ssh ubuntu@192.168.1.97
Last login: Fri Nov 27 18:16:13 2020 from 192.168.2.196
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for ubuntu.
Current password: ubuntu
New password: SNIP
Retype new password: SNIP
passwd: password updated successfully
Shared connection to 192.168.1.97 closed.
```

However, after filling out the enforced change-password prompt, the SSH connection is closed … and then attempting to SSH in again, with the new password, yields the *same prompt*:

```
❯ ~ [7s] ssh ubuntu@192.168.1.97
Last login: Fri Nov 27 18:16:21 2020 from 192.168.2.196
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for ubuntu.
Current password: SNIP
...
```

How can I disable this, or otherwise escape the infinite password-changing loop, to get into the system? I've tried wiping the SD-card and re-flashing a fresh copy, with the same results. Have also tried the newer, non-LTS Ubuntu Server 20.10, with the same results.

Comment: Read `man chage shadow`. You'll have to fix `/etc/shadow` very carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I think you either you need to:

1. Mount the "disk" from another Linux machine, and change the password from there.  You should be able to pull it off with a copy of busybox from the host platform, copied into the disk, and then `chroot`ing to the disk using the busybox for both a shell and the passwd command.
2. Attach a keyboard and monitor, and login normally.  While the password update might be broken in ssh, it should work on a console login.
3. Mount the "disk" from another Linux machine, and otherwise edit `/etc/shadow`.